# Skip a view with a segue

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uistoryboardsegue

I have a view that loads when the user launches the application without being logged in. From that view the user can click on a button to sign in, which results in a segue (let's call it `sequeToLogin`) to a login view. When the user clicks a sign-in-button on the login view, another segue (`segueToMain`) sends the user to the main view of the application.

I am fiddling with dependency injection in swift, and so far I have been using `prepareForSegue` to inject my dependencies.

I would like to be able to segue directly to the main view from the initial view, if the user is already logged in, either with an additional segue, or by changing both segues together, so I don't have to worry about the dependency injection. Is there a good way to do this?

With `performSegueWithIdentifier` I can go to the next view, but it doesn't seem to work to skip a view altogether.

Comment: Curious, why not just add a new segue to the main view from the initial view and call that one instead if the user is already logged in?

Comment: @AndrewRobinson I'll see if I can make that work, thanks for the suggestion!